# Unsure what's causing this invalid read in Valgrind

Tags: c, arrays, struct, valgrind

I have a function `bar(S* x, uint y)`, and a struct `S` defined as follows:

```
typedef struct S {
    T** arr;
    uint length;
} S;
```

where `length` is the length of the array the `arr` pointer points to, and `T` is some other struct. Said array is dynamically allocated with `calloc` when the struct is initialized in my code.

Now, inside `bar`, I have a call like this:

```
uint left = y*2+1;
uint right = y*2+2;
uint boundary = x->length-1;
bool left_exists = (left <= boundary && x->arr[left]); 
bool right_exists = (right <= boundary && x->arr[right]);
if (left_exists && right_exists) {//do something}
```

Now, my understanding is that if, for example, `right` refers to an invalid index, nothing will break, as the first part of the conditional will just short-circuit out of it.

However, I wrote a test of my program with an `x` such that `x->length` is 2, and called `bar` on it with a `y` of 0. The program doesn't segfault (as I expected), but I *do* get a warning from Valgrind about an invalid read of 8 bytes (the size of a pointer on my architecture) from this line:

```
bool right_exists = (right <= boundary && x->arr[right]);
```

I'm not sure what's causing this - I would understand if I actually executed `x->arr[right]`, but doesn't my code prevent this?

Comment: Don't declare the two `bool` variables on a single line like that; it makes the code unreadable, both on SO and in your work (or play) environment.  The `uint` declaration line doesn't do what you probably think it does, though it isn't really clear what you expect it to do.  But don't use the comma operator like that (it should be a last resort; it has its uses, but this isn't a good one), and don't put three statements, only one of which is a declaration, on a single line like that.  Yuck!  Yuck, yuck, yuck!!!

Comment: Also, since `valgrind` can report the line number the problem's on, if you put multiple statements on a single line, you're losing valuable debugging information about which statement is causing the trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Point very much taken. I've amended my question in line with your suggestions.

Comment: Much better.  Now, which line does `valgrind` report the problem on?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As I've indicated in my edited answer, ``bool right_exists = (right <= boundary && x->arr[right]);``

Comment: Is there a possibility the `x->length` is 0?  If so, `boundary` becomes very big.  You can use an `assert()` to make sure it isn't.  After that, we probably have to end up debugging the memory allocation code.  Have you added print statements to the code to ensure you know what's going on -- what the values are?  Is it a one-time problem or does it happen every time the code is called (assuming it is called more than once)?

Comment: You were absolutely right - it was underflow. I really have to watch that...